# Cannot start container : [8] System error: exec: "up3": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I checked the similar issue in Stack Overflow but not found what I expected answer. so hopefully my questions aren't too silly.
I cannot start my container after I created it.
I use the command:**`docker start 6069dba3cb02`**
and get the below error message:

```
root@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers# docker start 6069dba3cb02
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 6069dba3cb02: [8] System error: exec: "up3": executable file not found in $PATH
Error: failed to start containers: [6069dba3cb02]
```

[image]

The container info as below:

Even I use the other command: "`docker restart 6069dba3cb02`" or "`docker run ubuntu:14.04 up3`", I still get the error

Docker info: Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.8.0 (TCL 6.3);
Install path: https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases

Comment: can you show me your  Dockerfile?

Comment: After I install docker for Windows from https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases, I input the below comment: sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello World', it will download the ubuntu image, then type "docker create ubuntu:14.04 up3" that will create the container. I didn't create Dockerfile to generate image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to achieve with the parameter `up3`? This command is executed inside of the container you just started. But Ubuntu does not know this command, because it simply does not exist in the plain Ubuntu image (that's what the error message said: `executable file not found`).

Therefore you have to install your up3 tool before you try to access it. Or you have a misunderstanding about what up3 should do with your container, i don't know.

Try to replace `up3` with `ls /` or something like this to understand what the last arguments do when running docker:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu ls /
```

`--rm` removes the container after the command exits.

To give your container the name `up3`, you have to add this to your command:

```
docker create --name up3 ubuntu:14.04
```

Then you can start your container by name:

```
docker start up3
```

Comment: Thanks, the "up3" is container name which created by "docker create ubuntu:14.04 up3". but I cannot start the container.

Comment: up3 is not the container name here. up3 is still the command which docker trys to execute. To give it the name up3, you have to use `--name`, e.g. `docker create --name up3 ubuntu:14.04`